# How to make Show work in Mathematica 10 Kernel

Tags: plotting, kernel

Wolfram Research says it no longer supports JavaGraphics in Mathmatica 10.  This is very bad for people who prefer the Kernel to the FrontEnd.

However, I am still able to get it to work.

Show failed.  However, this works:

```
show[x__] := Show[x, DisplayFunction->$DisplayFunction ]
```

Also, ErrorListPlot fails, but this works:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
errorListPlot[x__] := show [ ErrorListPlot[x] ]
```

I put these definitions in my init.m file.

Sorry this isn't a question ... more of a tip.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: You could, instead, pose a question and then answer it, if you wish.

Comment: 1. JavaGraphics works fine for me in version 10, including `Show`.  2.  Why do you believe the command line to be superior to the notebook interface?  Unless you are using a slow Raspberry Pi, I don't see what you would gain, but you certainly do lose a lot.

Comment: Can you give more information about your setup so we can figure out why JavaGraphics doesn't work for you?  What is your OS, what *precise* version of Mathematica are you using?  How did you try to show the graphics precisely?  I have Mathematica 10.0.2 on OS X and in a fresh kernel I did ``Needs["JavaGraphics`"]; Show@Graphics[Circle[]]``.  This shows a window with a circle.