# How do I display graphics in the Wolfram Language kernel?

Tags: graphics

I'm unable to view graphics output when working directly with the kernel from a terminal window. How do I display graphics when working that way?

Comment: You need the Frontend for graphics.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates:  [(2911)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2911/121), [(13961)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13961/121), [(48239)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48239/121), [(75316)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75316/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the JavaGraphics package, run the following text in the kernel:

```
<<JavaGraphics`
```

Comment: You seem to be having trouble with the editor.  I formatted your code as I believe you intended.