# How to enable plotting?

Tags: graphics

10.3.0.0

In[9]:= Plot[x^2, {x,2,4}]

Out[9]= -Graphics-

I would like to see the actual plot? How do I get it?

Also, how do you back up along a line of input to make edits without using the backspace key and deleting all your work? Maybe, Wolfram want us to use other editors and simply paste into their app?

Comment: Try a clean start. http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Comment: Are you using the Notebook interface or some kind of terminal?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86113/2079

Answer (score 1):

Start the program called *Mathematica*, not the one called *MathKernel* or similar.

Based on your description, you have likely started the terminal interface on Windows.  Start the notebook interface.  That is how Mathematica is meant to be used.